# Replace one directory with another

Tags: unix, mv, rm

In `unix`, if I wanted to replace one file (e.g., `foo`) with another (e.g., `bar`), I would call

```
$ mv bar foo
```

`foo` would disappear, and `bar` would take its name.

Yet, if I wanted to replace one directory with another (again, `foo` and `bar`), this would not work:

```
$ mv bar foo
```

Here, the `bar` directory would be moved inside of the `foo` directory.

To replace `bar` with `foo`, I know I can do

```
$ rm -r foo
$ mv bar foo
```

But is there a way to accomplish this with one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's how mv works, when destination dir isn't exists - it will do move/rename, when exists - will move source dir into it. 
If you really need to do this often and would like to simplify this, you can use alias, for example smth like this:

```
rmandmv() {
    rm -r $2
    mv $1 $2
}
alias rmmv=rmandmv
```